# grails form submit calls wrong controller

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have two forms on my page. They are popups and through javascript they are shown/hidden. Both forms go to wrong controller. The action name is taken from form parameters, but the controller is taken from somewhere else.

```
    <!-- create queue form -->
<div id="popupCreateQueue" style="display: none;">
    <div id="queuePopupBody">
        <form controller="queueAAA" action="createAAA" name='createQueueForm'>
            <input id='popupQueueNameInput' name="queueName" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
            <input type="button" onclick="createQueueForm_hide()" value="Cancel">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- create activity form -->
<div id='popupCreateActivity' style="display: none;">
    <div id='activityPopupBody'>
        <form controller="activityBBB" action="createBBB" name='createActivityForm'>
            <input id='popupActivityNameInput' name="activityName" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
            <input type="button" onclick="createActivityForm_hide()" value="Cancel">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

First submit goes to `queue/createAAA?queueName=asd`

Second submit goes to `queue/createBBB?activityName=asd`

What happens here? Why some other controller is being called?

upd: i tried to renaming every "queue" in the page to some other name and still the controller called was "queue"

p.s. the buttons to show popups are inside , don't know if that matters.

Comment: you have to use <g:form> instead of <form> if you use controller/action params

Comment: thanks @droggo, you are correct. But i am curious, where from does the submit input takes controller name in the simple <form>?

Comment: if you use <g:form> tag, in fact you are using Grails taglib which renders more HTML than just what you defined. The best way to check is to verify HTML of the result page. In case of <g:form>, action param is generated from controller and action, so result is something like <form action="AppName/controller/action">...</form>

Comment: So, i could also use a simple form, but define the action with controller path <form action="AppName/controller/action"></form>?

Comment: You could, but why if you have a tag? tag resolves application name automatically, you dont have to hardcode it. Also is compatible with URLMappings if you modify them